# MsWord plugin with NetOffice automation - extracting image

Tags: c#, ms-office

I am converting an existing plugin written in VS2008 using the office 2007 PIA's into something more generic using NetOffice.

Everything seems to compile alright using the netoffice framework (with some minor code tinkering)

but my issue is that the only way to copy inlineshapes out of a word doc is using the clipboard, and in the netoffice example my clipboard value always comes out null. Reading on google it seem that this is linked to a threading issue with the clipboard. essentially my code code changed so I can only assume it as to do with how Netoffice creates it's proxies.

can anyone assist?

```
void commandBarBtn_Click(Office.CommandBarButton Ctrl, ref bool CancelDefault)
    {






        string str = _wordApplication.ActiveDocument.Content.Text;
        MessageBox.Show(str);

        try
        {
            int count = _wordApplication.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                //Clipboard.Clear();
                Word.InlineShape shape = _wordApplication.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes[i + 1];
                shape.Select();
                _wordApplication.Selection.CopyAsPicture();

                IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();  //always returns null. help!

                if (data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
                {
                    Bitmap bmp = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
                    string filename = String.Format(@"c:\image{0}.bmp", i.ToString());
                    bmp.Save(filename);
                }

                //Application.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }

        Ctrl.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is essentially how I got this working.
I am still not 100% sure why I needed to do this. essentially you can only access the clipboard from a static thread, and the NetOffice system seems to spawn off threads somewhere or another.

Here is what I did to get this working

```
    IDataObject data = null;

                Exception threadEx = null;
                Thread staThread = new Thread(
                    delegate()
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
                            if (data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
                            {
                                Bitmap bmp = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
                                string filename = String.Format(@"c:\image{0}.bmp", i.ToString());
                                bmp.Save(filename);
                            }
                        }

                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            threadEx = ex;
                        }
                    });
                staThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                staThread.Start();
                staThread.Join();
```